# Laravel Vapor file upload fails

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

Following the Laravel Vapor documentation for file uploads (https://docs.vapor.build/1.0/resources/storage.html#file-uploads), I'm encountering the following error when I try to upload the file from localhost to S3:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/vapor/signed-storage-url 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The laravel log states the following:

```
Unable to issue signed URL. Missing environment variables: AWS_BUCKET, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY at Http\\Controllers\\SignedStorageUrlController.php:107
```

All of those environment variables are defined in the .env file.

Any ideas on how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel Vapor uses the $_ENV array to read the environment variables. Mine was empty:

```
dd($_ENV) = []
```

After some research, I found out that php.ini has to be set to allow/enable PHP to set the $_ENV variables from -env. My local php-fpm Docker development setup had this disabled by default. I just had to update the variables_order = "EGPCS" to allow this to happen and then Vapor works correctly.

```
 && sed -E -i -e "s/variables_order.*/variables_order = \"EGPCS\"/g" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
```

I'm using Docker, but I assume if you enable or amend this in a local php.ini file you can get this working also.

Comment: For anyone encountering similar issues - after setting up the *variables_order* param like above, `config:cache` or `cache:clear` didn't had any effects. After running `rm bootstrap/cache/config.php` the **$_ENV** variable started being populated.

Answer (score 0):

Set AWS_BUCKET, AWS_DEFAULT_REGION, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY inside secrets area of Vapor dashboard or cli.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your env.production or whatever environment you are using

```
vapor env:pull production // or staging etc
```

Add those aws values in there then

```
vapor env:push production
```

Then deploy to your environment and your environment variables will be used.
Your .env is only local

Answer (score 0):

To use the S3 storage with vapor locally, you'll need to set the AWS environment variables into your .env.

These variables:
`AWS_BUCKET`, `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`, `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

When running in the vapor, these variables are injected into your environment during execution time.